# Shear capacity according to eurocode , when to use which equation

Tags: structural-engineering, shear, buckling

I am looking at eurocode to calculate shear capacity, and under section "6.2.6 Shear", there are two different shear checks:

Eq 6.18

[image]

Eq 6.19
[image]

When there is no torsion we can use equation 6.18?

But if we do have torsion we have to use eq 6.19? - but I am not sure what buckling verification in section 5 of EN 1993-1-5 theyre referring to, but will I have to do all the checks in section 5?

Link to EN 1993-1-5: https://www.phd.eng.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Equation 6.18 is the "design **plastic** shear resistance", and equation 6.19 is the limiting shear stress for the "design **elastic** shear resistance. Hope this clears the confusion.